# Boost converter output instability

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm currently working on a DC-DC boost converter project and encountering this issue where the output initially peaks but falls back to the input voltage. My desired output is around 140 V.

[image]

I'm using an [LTC4444-5 gate driver](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/44445fc.pdf).

Comment: If you have no control loop around your boost converter, you can't expect the output to be well-regulated.

Comment: @JohnD that isn't the case with a synchronous boost converter (when driven appropriately) because it can remain in CCM for any load condition and, with decent MOSFETs, the output voltage is pretty well defined by the input voltage and duty cycle.

Comment: @Andyaka Sure, but transient response can be an issue.

Comment: It isn't perfect but, it's not-bad (unless the load varies by a vast amount very quickly in a short length of time) and, you are somehow hampered by lack of output capacitors. Thank you for the u/v btw @JohnD

Comment: Voting to close, as insufficient information is available to answer: gate signals are not shown, the control circuit if any is not shown, and Vin is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will happen on your design because without input current limiting (or an inductor bypass circuit) the initial transient of supply voltage will form an RLC low-pass filter of fairly decent Q and, you'll get initial overshoot when first applying power.

Of course this isn't a problem when boosting higher than 1:2 because the maximum overshoot is limited to twice the incoming supply voltage but, when only lightly boosting a voltage (less than 1:2) you can suffer from overshoot.

Comment: A very inappropriate downvote has been noted. The 2nd one in ten minutes (2 different answers) so, maybe if they are unconnected, the person leaving this downvote can explain their reason. Of course, their reason will be wrong (because I know I am correct in my answer).

Comment: Wasn't me- Upvoting.